# How does one manage object pooling in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, object-pooling

It's my understanding that in Spring, all objects are treated by default as singletons.  If singleton is set to false, then a new object will be served at each request.

But what if I wanted to pool objects?  Say set a range from a min of 1 to a max of 10 instances?  Is this possible using Spring?

Comment: I wouldn't see how it would be any different then using it in the Summer, Fall or Winter http://hiyoooo.com

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pooling can be applied to any POJO with spring.

See [here](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop-api.html#aop-ts-pool) for more information.

Comment: +1 I think the real work here is being done by commons-pool, but this sounds like a good way to enable it

Comment: This is the sort of thing that makes Spring cool - take an off-the-shelf, best-of-breed open source library, and wrap it so that you can use it the same IoC way as everything else. Sweet.

Comment: FYI, [link for the current](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ts-pool).